# Adding an additional key-value pair to objects in a list before passing it to a Template - Working, but I'm not sure why

Tags: django, django-models

New to Django and I wanted to append a key:value pair to each Job object in a Queryset/list before passing it to a template. Researching on here it says you can't just append a field, but rather need to create a new dict or could possibly add attributes or something, but messing around I got it to work great, but logically it seems it shouldn't work, and I worry I may run into problems or data inconsistency somewhere.

My "jobs" view gets all Jobs currently not assigned to a User, filters out Jobs based on the current signed in Users listed skillset(a custom field for my User model), and then the functionatily I'm adding is to check the current Users schedule, and add a value `"conflict":True` if the schedule conflicts so I can highlight it red when rendering the list of jobs to the screen.

views.py (abbreviated):

```
    def jobs (request):

      //get all unassigned jobs, and create a list of only jobs where the user has matching skills
        available = Job.objects.filter(assigned_to__isnull=True).order_by('start_time').all()
        available = [job for job in available if request.user.is_skilled(job)]

      //go through each job, make it a dict, and add "conflict":True to it if scheudle confict
        for job in available:
            if not request.user.is_available(job):
                job = job.__dict__
                job["conflict"] = True

      //run custom serializer() to format each field and return list of jobs
        return JsonResponse({'available': [job.serialize() for job in available]})
```

The part that doesn't make sense to me is `job.__dict__` should be converting the job object to a dict, so I actually expected to get an error when I attempt to run `job.serialize()`. Infact, there is another view where I attempt the same thing with a single Job object(not a list or Queryset) and it gives error `Dict does not contain method serialize()`. And if I don't first convert to dict I get an error `TypeError: 'Job' object does not support item assignment`. But somehow when working with a list, the conversion doesn't occur, but my Job object now has a new field "conflict" that I can check with `job.conflict` in JS, templates, and in the serialize() model method:

models.py (abbreviated):

```
class Job (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    skillsets = models.ManyToManyField(Skillset, related_name="jobs")

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'description': self.description,
            'start_time': self.start_time.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
            'end_time': self.end_time.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
            'skillsets': [skill.title for skill in self.skillsets.all()],
            'conflict': self.conflict if 'conflict' in self.__dict__ else False,
        }
```

So question is, why does `available` contain a list of only Job objects after I should have converted some of them to Dict? I do this again on the User's object later to highlight users who are available for a particular Job, and same thing, even though I supposedly convert to Dict and add a field, the final output is a list of User objects with an added field `available`. I was expecting `assignable` to be a list of dicts, not a list of user objects:

Also in views.py:

```
def job_details (request, job_id):    
  //get a single Job, and list of users who are specialist, then filter out users who don't have required skills
    job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
    users = User.objects.filter(user_type=User.SPECIALIST)
    users = list(filter(lambda usr: usr.is_skilled(job), users))

  //for each user, check their schedule against this job, and add "available":True/False as determined
    for usr in users:
        if (usr.is_available(job)):
            usr = usr.__dict__
            usr["available"] = True
        else:
            usr = usr.__dict__
            usr["available"] = False

  //return job and users to be rendered on screen, colored based on their availability
    return render(request, "jobs/job_details.html", {
        'job': job.serialize(),
        'assignable': users,
        'conflict': True if request.user.user_type == User.SPECIALIST and not request.user.is_available(job) else False})
```

Is there a logical explaination? Is it because I'm doing it in a for loop that the conversion doesn't stick, but the field gets added to the User/Job objects, like is it converting back after it exits the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

To address your immediate question - the statement `usr = usr.__dict__` done when iterating over the list simply assigns a variable `usr`. It does not change the element in the original list. To transform the list of model instances to dicts, you can use `map` function, or list comprehension. For example:

```
users = list(map(lambda usr: {**usr.__dict__, "available": usr.is_available(job)}, users))
```

BTW, probably slightly better approach would be to set "available" attribute right on the model instance, and then access it in `serialize` method via [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr): `getattr(self, "available", False)`.

Or, you can take it a step further and add `available` as a [python property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to model class. Then you will be able to document its meaning and usage:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def available(self):
        """Document the meaning..."""
        return getattr(self, "_available", False)

    @available.setter
    def available(self, value):
        self._available = value
```

Comment: And I thought that about the usr variable and changes done in the for loop, map would have been better except I was initially attempting to modify the objects, but the question is why does this work? If I'm creating a dict and modifying it, why does my list of objects get the new appended value?

Comment: And thanks for suggesting Attr... not something I'm familiar with yet, and will look into that as a better option.

Comment: > why does my list of objects get the new appended value?

`list(map(...))` does not append values to existing list. It produces a new list.

Comment: OK, spent some time in the shell today messing with the above. From the above it seem usr.__dict__, usr["conflict"]=True shouldn't have worked, but testing shows it just appended an attribute to my object instance.... I've since found out I can do this with just usr.conflict=True, without first converting to dict. So I guess my final question regarding this is that if you can just easily append an attribute to an object for a specific rendering requirement, is there a reason all answers on here suggest more complicated solution to this type of question?

Comment: Can you provide a couple of examples of such answers/solutions?

Comment: Seems this one states to build a new dataset rather than just adding a field(attribute) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633648/django-views-add-field-to-model-and-return-to-template -           This one seems to want to do exactly what I was doing, but in the end he created a new list and then added stuff to the new list:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412193/injecting-custom-data-into-django-queryset-before-passing-to-template...  And found several others, but seems easily solveble just tacking on with dot notation.. job.conflic=True in a loop.

Comment: And for some reason tonight I can't find the one I found multiple times before that states to create a second dict, and link it to the additional data:     newdict = { "objectfromlist": object, "newvalue": value}    so that you can tie the new field to the list of objects....

Comment: The answer to the second question uses `setattr` to set the attribute on model instance. Which is essentially the same as setting attribute via dot notation (`obj.attr = value`). Django is python, and python is dynamic language where you can easily change objects on the fly, in different ways. The idea in the answer to first question is to produce a new datastructure that is easy to work with from the template, rather than extending the model instance. That can also be sensible. As you see, there are multiple ways to approach similar problems.

Comment: Thanks. I've learned a lot about structures and modification. Still not sure why running a loop where I convert dict, then use [] notation to add a kv pair resulted in a list of objects with an added attribute, sure that answer is embedded in the behind-the-scenes handling, but this definitely helps :).